# How to add active class to menu and sub menu items with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to JS/ jQuery, I am trying to add active class to my menu items on click, also to submenu items.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#pag").click(function() {
    $("span > label").removeClass("activ");
    $(this).addClass("activ");
  });
});
```

```css
.activ {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="pag" class="list-group">
  <a class="list-group-item " href="#">Choose</a><br>
  <span>
    <label class="list-group-item activ " for="tbavtive1">Main1</label>
    <li class="subs" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Subs 1</li>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu " x-placement="bottom-start">
      <label class="dropdown-item Stu" for="tbavtive2">Lorem 1</label>  
    </ul>
  </span>
  <span>
    <label class="list-group-item Stu" for="tbavtive9">Main2</label>
    <li class="subs" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
      Sub2
      <i class="zmdi zmdi-plus zmdi-hc-fw"></i>
    </li>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu " x-placement="bottom-start">
      <label class="dropdown-item Stu" for="tbavtive10">Lorem 2</label>
    </ul>
  </span>
</ul>
```

But my code not working, can anybody help me with this?

Comment: Part of of the problem is because your HTML is invalid. Only `li` or `ol` elements can be a child of a `ul`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you are adding a class to `$(this)` which points to `ul`. changing your code so that click event will be fired only when a child `label` of `#pag`

finally `$(this).addClass("activ");` because `$('this')` is the actual clicked on label.

Here is a working snippet

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#pag label").click(function() {
    $("#pag label").removeClass("activ");
    $(this).addClass("activ");
  });
});
```

```css
.activ {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="pag" class="list-group">
  <a class="list-group-item " href="#">Choose</a><br>
  <span>
    <label class="list-group-item activ " for="tbavtive1">Main1</label>
    <li class="subs" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Subs 1</li>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu " x-placement="bottom-start">
      <label class="dropdown-item Stu" for="tbavtive2">Lorem 1</label>  
    </ul>
  </span>
  <span>
    <label class="list-group-item Stu" for="tbavtive9">Main2</label>
    <li class="subs" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
      Sub2
      <i class="zmdi zmdi-plus zmdi-hc-fw"></i>
    </li>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu " x-placement="bottom-start">
      <label class="dropdown-item Stu" for="tbavtive10">Lorem 2</label>
    </ul>
  </span>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue with your code is that you are adding event handler on parent `ul`. So in `$(this).addClass("activ");` this will point to UL and not Label.

You need to attach event on label instead.

Also few pointers:

- Use delegate. Instead of `.click`, use `.on(eventName, handler)`. This will work for dynamically added elements as well.
- Instead of `$("span > label").removeClass("activ");`, do `$("span > label.activ").removeClass("activ");`. DOM manipulation is very expensive. So only fetch those elements that have `activ` class

**Following is a sample code**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#pag label.list-group-item").on('click', function() {
    $("span > label.activ").removeClass("activ");
    $(this).addClass("activ");
  });
});
```

```css
.activ {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="pag" class="list-group">
  <a class="list-group-item " href="#"> Choose
    </a><br>
  <span>
        <label class="list-group-item activ " for="tbavtive1">
           Main1 </label>
        <li class="subs" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            Subs 1         
        </li>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu " x-placement="bottom-start">
            <label class="dropdown-item Stu" for="tbavtive2">Lorem 1</label>  
        </ul>
    </span>
  <span>
        <label class="list-group-item Stu" for="tbavtive9">
            Main2
        </label>
        <li class="subs" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            Sub2
            <i class="zmdi zmdi-plus zmdi-hc-fw"></i>
        </li>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu " x-placement="bottom-start">
            <label class="dropdown-item Stu" for="tbavtive10">Lorem 2</label>
        </ul>
    </span>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything inside `<ul>` should start with `<li>` tag, fix your code the code below should work just fine.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
            $("#pag li").click(function () {
                $(this).parent().add("li.activ").removeClass("activ");
                $(this).addClass("activ");
            });
        });
```

```css
.activ {
  color:red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="pag" class="list-group">
    <a class="list-group-item " href="#"> Choose</a><br>
   <span>
        <label class="list-group-item activ " for="tbavtive1">
           Main1 </label>
        <li class="subs" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            Subs 1         
        </li>
        <li>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu " x-placement="bottom-start">
              <label class="dropdown-item Stu" for="tbavtive2">Lorem 1</label>  
          </ul>
        </li>
    </span>
    <span>
        <label class="list-group-item Stu" for="tbavtive9">
            Main2
        </label>
        <li class="subs" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            Sub2
            <i class="zmdi zmdi-plus zmdi-hc-fw"></i>
        </li>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu " x-placement="bottom-start">
            <label class="dropdown-item Stu" for="tbavtive10">Lorem 2</label>
        </ul>
    </span>
</ul>
```